# Change the back ground color of the text box inside the gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on a asp.net application where i am able to load the data from the SQL to the gridview in aspx page.User has the ability to edit and save the values in the gridview.
My grid view has the itemtemplates where i have two colums with textboxes.I want to highlight all the cells with a different color which user edits in the gridview.

I am able to do the same thing for the textboxes in another aspx page with out gridview with java script with the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(':input').change(function() {

                $(this).addClass("textchanged");

            });

        });

    </script>



 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvnames" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
            Font-Names="Georgia" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" BackColor="White"
            BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" DataKeyNames="Name"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
           >
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
<colums>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName"  Visible='<%# !(bool) IsInEditMode %>' runat="server"
                                Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Width="250px" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
</colums>
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

When i try to implement the same code for the text box inside a grid view its doesn't work.
Is is the right approach or is there any other way to achieve ?
I would appreciate if some one can guide me in right path.

Comment: Your code works. You should look for the problem somewhere else. Does jQuery function correctly on the page?

Comment: Yeah i am still figuring out where the problem is...I have a content place holder where i placed the script.I did include the gridview inside a panel .Does panel has some thing to do with that??

Comment: No, Panel should be no problem... would be nice to see some markup... but jQuery works properly on page?!

Comment: Just added the mark up of the grdview.

Comment: @Jan-FrederikCarl :Its working for me now i am not sure what happened yesterday.One more question i have about the jquery change function...the only time the change function fires when the current text is changed ..if i add some thing to the existing text it doesnt change the back ground color..is this the way the change function works ?

Comment: Yes, you can look it up in the jQuery-doc, http://api.jquery.com/change/:  "event is deferred until the element loses focus"

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should remove the : that is in front of the word input in your jquery.  Additionally if this is only supposed to happen to textboxes then you should be more specific in your jquery selector and change it to this:

```
 $('input[type=text]')
```

Comment: looks like its working using the same code which i mentioned in my question.Will try this way too.

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, please change the

```
<colums><colums>
```

-tag to

```
<Columns></Columns>
```

This should help, if jQuery runs properly